# Move a message to subscription deadletter for failed HTTP request

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-subscriptions

I've been looking for resources but I can't seem to find what I need.. I have an Azure function with a Service Bus trigger. From this, I make an HTTP call with one of the values found in the Service Bus message.

An additional requirement for me is to deadletter a message if it the HTTP call fails. But as I understand it, the message is not present in the subscription anymore because it was properly received. Is there a way for me to keep the message in the subscription, and then dispose it once it is successful (transfer to DLQ if not?)

I found this piece of code but I'm not sure how it's sending to the DLQ?
https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/azure-servicebus_7.3.0/sdk/servicebus/azure-servicebus/samples/sync_samples/receive_deadlettered_messages.py

```
"""
Example to show receiving dead-lettered messages from a Service Bus Queue.
"""

# pylint: disable=C0111

import os
from azure.servicebus import ServiceBusClient, ServiceBusMessage, ServiceBusSubQueue

CONNECTION_STR = os.environ['SERVICE_BUS_CONNECTION_STR']
QUEUE_NAME = os.environ["SERVICE_BUS_QUEUE_NAME"]

servicebus_client = ServiceBusClient.from_connection_string(conn_str=CONNECTION_STR)

with servicebus_client:
    sender = servicebus_client.get_queue_sender(queue_name=QUEUE_NAME)
    messages = [ServiceBusMessage("Message to be deadlettered") for _ in range(10)]
    with sender:
        sender.send_messages(messages)

    print('dead lettering messages')
    receiver = servicebus_client.get_queue_receiver(queue_name=QUEUE_NAME)
    with receiver:
        received_msgs = receiver.receive_messages(max_message_count=10, max_wait_time=5)
        for msg in received_msgs:
            print(str(msg))
            receiver.dead_letter_message(msg)

    print('receiving deadlettered messages')
    dlq_receiver = servicebus_client.get_queue_receiver(queue_name=QUEUE_NAME, sub_queue=ServiceBusSubQueue.DEAD_LETTER)
    with dlq_receiver:
        received_msgs = dlq_receiver.receive_messages(max_message_count=10, max_wait_time=5)
        for msg in received_msgs:
            print(str(msg))
            dlq_receiver.complete_message(msg)

print("Receive is done.")
```

Here is a code snippet in mine:

```
async def main(msg: func.ServiceBusMessage):
    try:
        logging.info('Python ServiceBus queue trigger processed message: %s',
        msg.get_body().decode('utf-8'))
        await asyncio.gather(wait(), wait())

        result = json.dumps({
            'message_id': msg.message_id,
            'metadata' : msg.metadata
        })

        msgobj = json.loads(result)

        val = msgobj['metadata']['value']
        run_pipeline(val, msg)
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"trigger failed: {e}")
```

TLDR; How do I keep the message in the subscription and either dispose them (if successful) or send them to the DLQ if not?

Comment: What happens in your code currently when an exception occurs?

Comment: I'm actually doing a POST request that triggers an azure pipeline using some details found in the message, so if that fails, the pipeline won't be triggered. it was asked if it was possible for me to dead letter the message inserted into the subscription.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, if your Function throws an exception the message will be returned back to the Subscription so that it can be processed again. After certain number of retries (configured at the Subscription level), the message will be automatically dead-lettered. Can you try by throwing an exception from your Function code. I believe currently you're just consuming it in your code.

Comment: I just tested it out, it seems like it's still removing it even with the exception. I'll update the post with my code.

Comment: Would you happen to know how to switch from receive and delete to peek lock?

Answer (score 0):

The code that you pasted is to *Recieve Deadletter Messages* from the deadletter queue.

I found some code in the [docs](https://azuresdkdocs.blob.core.windows.net/$web/python/azure-servicebus/latest/index.html#id16). You can use this snippet from their example

```
from azure.servicebus import ServiceBusClient

import os
connstr = os.environ['SERVICE_BUS_CONNECTION_STR']
queue_name = os.environ['SERVICE_BUS_QUEUE_NAME']

with ServiceBusClient.from_connection_string(connstr) as client:
    with client.get_queue_receiver(queue_name) as receiver:
        for msg in receiver:
            print(str(msg))
            receiver.dead_letter_message(msg)
```

You can look at using this above code in your Exception handler

Answer (score 0):

There're [four methods](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/tree/main/sdk/servicebus/azure-servicebus#settle-a-message-after-receipt) to settle a message after receipt:

- Complete:
  Declares the message processing to be successfully completed, removing the message from the queue.

```py
receiver.complete_message(msg)
```

- Abandon:
  Abandon processing of the message for the time being, returning the message immediately back to the queue to be picked up by another (or the same) receiver.

```py
receiver.abandon_message(msg)
```

- DeadLetter:
  Transfer the message from the primary queue into the DQL.

```py
receiver.dead_letter_message(msg)
```

- Defer:
  Defer is subtly different from the prior settlement methods. It prevents the message from being directly received from the queue by setting it aside.

```py
receiver.defer_message(msg)
```

To answer your question "How do I keep the message in the subscription and either dispose them (if successful) or send them to the DLQ if not?":

- keep the message in the subscription: use `abandon_message`
- dispose them (if successful): use `complete_message`
- send them to the DLQ: use `dead_letter_message`